# String to html table in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

```
string htmltable = "<table><tr><th>Head1</th><th>Head2</th><tr><td>data</td><td>Data</td></tabel>";
```

This string I am getting in veiw by calling class which generates string for me. I need to parse this string as table in my view.

In view I am calling

`@TestProject.Html.tableCreation()`

It's returning me a string.

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: htmltable="<tabel><tr><th>Headder1</th><th>Header2</th></tr>";

Comment: Your question is not clear? Can you take time to rewrite it?

Comment: What do you mean you need to parse it as a table?  If it's a string, can't you just emit the string to the view?  When it gets to the client, it'll be treated as HTML like any other.  During server-side processing, _all_ HTML is "a string."

Comment: Thank u so much for quick reply just emiting the string to view..but string is getting displayed as it is in view !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you change this a bit and create a HTML helper that returns a MvcHtmlString.
For example:

```
public static MvcHtmlString CreateTable<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper,  string htmlString)
{
//Build table logic here using TagBuilder or System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table
   return MvcHtmlString.Create(htmlString);
}
```

To use in your view @Html.CreateTable("Your string here"Could do the url.action()... as well );

If this does not work you can use javascript to embed the html into a div tag...

Comment: retslig Thank u :) Hats off!!

Comment: Hi Retslig need some basic info.. As i m getting string from external CS file (I mean CS file  is not in MVC structure nor its in model) will this breaks the MVC?

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is a separate C# assembly? If so that is not a problem, you just need to reference that assembly and call the method to return this string in the above helper.

Comment: I m refering the helperclass(which is returing MVCHTML String) from diffrent Project of same solution. My concern is, Is it acceptable to call the external class from view like this in MVC Structure? Will this breaks MVC pattren.. ? Sorry  for my poor english!!

Comment: I see, first off I will let you know that I don't follow the MVC pattern strictly.  With that being said I do believe in patterns and practices but I think some deviation is good. With that being said I have a whole separate project of MVC helpers.  It includes shared controllers, shared content, shared models etc... where they are common to many of my projects and fundamental code. So yes in my opinion that is perfectly acceptable.  Sorry for the long winded response but these questions are often very debatable. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the table as a string from server side. 
Now you just need to append it.

```
$("body").append(htmltable)
```